# Convert dynamic and complex html code with SVG embedded to PDF in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf, svg

I'm getting desperate trying to get my dynamic code, from a database, and frontend-modified, composed of HTML code and a SVG embedded image, into a single PDF to download. I say, the same effect as if I press CTRL+P in the browser, and selecting a PDF printer. I think the idea is very simple, but I'm not able to get it at all. I'm using Angular JS to get the code from database, and attach the SVG image as background image for my data.

I've tried makepdf and others, but only with jspdf I got some results from an image, but not combining HTML code + SVG dynamically.

Maybe, another possibility could be convert HTML + SVG to PNG, and then get that PNG into PDF.

Which one do you recommend me? And how could I achieve it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Had you tried using something like this https://livecodestream.dev/post/convert-web-pages-into-pdfs-with-puppeteer-and-nodejs/

Comment: Yes!!! I didn't know that solution. Thank you VERY much! I spent many weeks in several tries to get this working. It's perfect!